# New form failing in Rails 4 with undefined method for one of the form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0
Windows 8.1

When I try to create a new hobbyist, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `organization' for #<Hobbyist:0x000000070d0ac8>
```

With the following additional error details:

```
    block in _app_views_hobbyists__form_html_erb__2100369257_59197480
    app/views/hobbyists/_form.html.erb, line 8
    _app_views_hobbyists__form_html_erb__2100369257_59197480
    app/views/hobbyists/_form.html.erb, line 1
    _app_views_hobbyists_new_html_erb__583593320_59167000
    app/views/hobbyists/new.html.erb, line 3
```

Any ideas:

This is the controller:

```
  class hobbyistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_hobbyist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /hobbyists
  # GET /hobbyists.json
  def index
    @hobbyists = hobbyist.all
  end

  # GET /hobbyists/1
  # GET /hobbyists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /hobbyists/new
  def new
    @hobbyist = hobbyist.new
  end

  # GET /hobbyists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /hobbyists
  # POST /hobbyists.json
  def create
    @hobbyist = hobbyist.new(hobbyist_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hobbyist.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hobbyist, notice: 'hobbyist was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hobbyist }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @hobbyist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /hobbyists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /hobbyists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @hobbyist.update(hobbyist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @hobbyist, notice: 'hobbyist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @hobbyist }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @hobbyist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /hobbyists/1
  # DELETE /hobbyists/1.json
  def destroy
    @hobbyist.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to hobbyists_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_hobbyist
      @hobbyist = hobbyist.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def hobbyist_params
      params.require(:hobbyist).permit(:first, :last, :salutation, :organization, :work_phone, :mobile_phone, :fax_phone, :other_phone, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip)
    end
end
```

This is the hobbyist new view

```
<h1>New hobbyist</h1>

<%= render 'form' %> (THIS IS LINE 3)

<%= link_to 'Back', hobbyists_path %>
```

This is the hobbyist __form view

```
<%= simple_form_for(@hobbyist) do |f| %> (THIS IS LINE 1)
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first %>
    <%= f.input :last %>
    <%= f.input :salutation %>
    <%= f.input :organization %> (THIS IS LINE 8)
    <%= f.input :work_phone %>
    <%= f.input :mobile_phone %>
    <%= f.input :fax_phone %>
    <%= f.input :other_phone %>
    <%= f.input :address1 %>
    <%= f.input :address2 %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :state %>
    <%= f.input :zip %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please confirm you have `organization` in your Hobbyist model - either as a physical column in the table (check schema.db) or as an attribute (show your Hobbyist model).

Comment: Also your controller code is showing lowercase 'h' on hobbyist in places like the first line where you define the class, and also where you refer to the model (e.g. `hobbyist.new`) - don't know if that is just how you showed the code here because you would surely get a load more problems if your controller is really like that.

Comment: The lower case "h" is because I created the question in a "smart" editor. The problem was that "organization" was not in the table (all the other fields were). I created a migration for it, and that took care of the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  You should probably either post and accept an answer or delete the question so it doesn't still appear as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"organization" was missing from the table. I fixed the problem by adding a migration to include "organization". The lower case h in the question are a side effect of having used a "smart" editor to compose the question before posting stackoverflow.